# What is the "start parameters" text box means in the Services properties box?

Tags: windows-xp, services

it have the description of "You can specify the start parameters that apply when you start the service from here". but i dont get what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically extra commands to a program if it supports it.

For example, an application may be multi core aware but by default only uses one core, the developer may make it take up multiple cores if started with the switch /cores 2 or if a program can span to multiple GBs of memory, there may be a switch that tells it the maximum it can take up - /maxmemory 1024

It is not built in and always there "because it is a service", it is something specific to each individual service programmed by the developer.

Comment: Basically they're just command-line parameters you pass to an executable file. They vary from service to service, check the service help docs for what parameters it accepts.

Comment: its the same as command line parameters? because i am trying to read any parameter from the program and i got 0 zero parameters altought i am writing "/Debug" in this text box

Comment: Another caveat with the "Start parameters" field, the values you enter are not saved.  Every time you close the dialog, the values are lost; if you open it again, you'll find the field blank.

Note that the "start parameters" are different than the args that appear in the "Path to executable".  Start Parameters are passed to the ServiceMain in the lpServiceArgVectors function argument as documented here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nc-winsvc-lpservice_main_functiona
The app needs to be coded to process these extra parameters.