# Windows 7 services not remembering start parameters

Tags: windows-7

How do I get windows 7 to remember the parameters passed to it.

I've tried to stop the service first.
Add the paramters.
Press start.
And then click OK.

However, they are still blank after re-opening the service.

It seems to be rather broken?

Comment: Unfortunately according to the documentation that's how it's supposed to work and I could find any way round it.

Comment: Related [What is the "start parameters" text box means in the Services properties box?](http://superuser.com/questions/70038/what-is-the-start-parameters-text-box-means-in-the-services-properties-box)